# Can multiple Rails Applications share models/common business domain data between them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have several use cases that manipulate and add to the same data at different points in the process.

Each of these use cases share many of the same models, and actions in the process but would require totally different views and structure.

I was thinking of trying out the tips in this article from 8thLight but this was written in 2007.

http://blog.8thlight.com/jim-suchy/2007/02/20/sharing-a-database-among-multiple-rails-applications.html

According to them, the trick is to

(1) make a new folder with the shared models right above the application.

```
applications_in_same_business_domain
    |-shared_models
    |-application1
    |-application2
    |-...
```

(2) require this new folder or module in your application via enviorments.rb file
   (which I believe the equivalent would be config/application.rb because I don't see enviornments.rb in Rails 3.)

They say some code like this will work (in environments.rb)

```
 $: << File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/your_lib_path'
```

I tried this and it isn't working (in application.rb)...

```
   config.autoload_paths += %W(../../../mardom_shared_models)
```

Is this the standard way to do this?

An API sounds like another way to do this...but...I don't know anything about API's here. Self-learning 6-Month Noob here)

Helping me get the above to work if it is possible I guess would be the specific question. Can I do this?

But any comments or articles on other matter would be appreciated.

I would need to modify the Rails generators here starting from this link: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

Comment: I think you may be looking for [Rails::Engine](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather put all models related stuff into a gem, and install gem locally to vengor/gems directory to simplify navigating in it.